# ASP.Net DropDownList selected value

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

I have a feeling I'm missing something really obvious, I'm not able to capture the selected value of my DropDownList; the value renaubs the first item on the list.  I have set the DropListList **autopostback** property to **true**.  I have a SelectedIndexChangedEvent which is pasted below.  This is NOT on the master page.

```
protected void ddlRestCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        r_city = ddlRestCity.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here is the DropDownList control:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRestCity" runat="server" 
        Width="100px" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ddlRestCity_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Thanx in advance for your help!

Comment: Where is your `DataBind()` call? Are you checking `!IsPostBack` before the call?

Comment: you all are write jock, every one know basic thing

Comment: thanks for -1 to all of us.I'll remove my answer.
you could at least explain why

Comment: you can vote whatever you think. If you decide to down vote all the answer in one page because maybe you disagree them you can but at least leave a comment about it. that it :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My off the cuff guess is you are maybe re-populating the list on a post back and that is causing the selected index to get reset.

Answer (score 8):

Where is your `DataBind()` call? Are you checking `!IsPostBack` before the call? For example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        ddlRestCity.DataSource = ...;
        ddlRestCity.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**Explanation:** If you don't check for `!IsPostBack` before `DataBind()`, the list will re-populate *before* `SelectedIndexChanged` is fired (because `Page.Load` fires *before* child events such as `SelectedIndexChanged`). When `SelectedIndexChanged` is then fired, the "selected item" is now the first item in the newly-populated list.

Answer (score 0):

What is r_city?

If it's a textbox, then you need to do something like `r_city.text = ...`

Also -- you might consider removing your postback check.  Usually, that's most useful in the page.onload event, and usually, you're checking for `if NOT ispostback`...